# Rails3 form_tag routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble getting a view and controller to play nice together.  I think I messed up my routing, any help would be great.

My controller looks like:

```
class AccountDetailsController < ApplicationController

    def new
      puts "in new"
    end

    def home
      puts "in home"
    end
end
```

My routes.rb looks like:

```
resources :account_details
```

My new.html.erb looks like:

```
<h1>AccountDetails#new</h1>
<%= form_tag(url_for(:controller => "account_details", :action => "new"), :method => "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

when I goto http://localhost:3000/account_details/new
I get my page and when I hit submit, I get this error:

Started POST "/account_details/new" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 at Wed May 02 22:38:10 -0400 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/account_details/new"):

Other than being clueless, what am I doing wrong?  I thought my route would cover the [POST], no?

Answer (score 0):

The proper method for creating new entry is PUT, not POST. You should remove `:method => "post"` from your template, so PUT method will be chosen automatically.